# Using ClickOnce Deployment need to include: Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS Office 2007 Add-In

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clickonce

All,

We are using ClickOnce to deploy our WPF application and have the need to include the 2007 Microsoft Office Add-in: Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS.

Is there a way to include this exe file in the ClickOnce deployment?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the install package for that. Then you can create a prerequisite package for it and deploy it as a prerequisite to your ClickOnce deployment.

To create the prerequisite package, you can use the Bootstrapper Manifest Generator, which is [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/92d68fc3-3c00-4435-9d45-f781aad89ad1).

You then copy this package to the a folder where the VS prerequisites are found. If you are using VS2010, that location is here:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages

If you are using VS2008, it's here:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages

[This post](http://jcrawfor74.wordpress.com/2008/02/27/bootstrap-manifest-generator-how-to-custom-pre-requisites/) can be helpful explaining how to use the BMG. Be sure to add an Error Code of 0 for success, or it will always tell you the install failed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the .exe to the deployment (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043746/how-to-add-external-file-to-application-files-clickonce-net)) and run check on program startup if it's installed, and run the process if not.